# event listener on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, counter, addeventlistener

I have 6 'like' buttons, clicking on which, counter increase. How can i use event handler on all 'like' buttons. In my example only the last one is working.

```
constructor(model) {
        this.count = 0;

        for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
           this.renderInitialTodoForm();
        } 

        this.likeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.count++;
            this.likeCount.innerHTML = this.count;
        })
    }

    renderInitialTodoForm = () => {
        this.app = this.getElement('#root');
  
        this.likeButton = this.createElement('span', 'likeImg');
        this.likeButton.textContent = '';

        this.likeCount = this.createElement('span', 'like');
        this.likeCount.textContent = 0;

        this.app.append( this.likeButton, this.likeCount);
    };
```

Comment: Do they have same CSS class?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What's `this` and the various methods that are called here? If you want one listener for all buttons, you can add it to the parent and use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55452921/6243352) to determine which was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You render 6 like buttons but only keep a reference to one - `this.likeButton`.  It is set to the last button created.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the event listener to each button inside the loop.

You can do that by either adding the code bloc to `renderInitialTodoForm` or directly inside the for loop.

```
constructor(model) {

        for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
           this.renderInitialTodoForm();
        } 
    
    }

    renderInitialTodoForm = () => {

        this.count = 0;

        this.app = this.getElement('#root');
  
        this.likeButton = this.createElement('span', 'likeImg');
        this.likeButton.textContent = '';
    
        this.likeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.count++;
            this.likeCount.innerHTML = this.count;
        })

        this.likeCount = this.createElement('span', 'like');
        this.likeCount.textContent = 0;

        this.app.append( this.likeButton, this.likeCount);
    };
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: if I click on any of the buttons, then one counter increases, which is the last

Comment: I think you it's because you will end up having only one count. We should create a new one evertime we create a new button. If you look closely, you are callend append with the same attribute `this.likeCount`. I will try to fix my response so you can try again.